# Q_PROPERTY macro within another macro

Tags: c++, qt, properties, macros, c-preprocessor

How to put the `Q_PROPERTY` macro inside another, helper-macro?

```
#define SimpleAllinOne(member, _type) \
  public: \
  void Set##member(_type _arg_##member) \
  { \
    m_##member = _arg_##member;\
  } \
  _type Get##member() const\
  { \
    return m_##member;\
  } \
  private: \
    _type m_##member; \
    Q_PROPERTY(_type member READ Get##member WRITE Set##member)
```

.. does not work. Preprocessor output (`gcc -E flag` or `nmake/jom /P flag`) shows the (working) setter/getter methods and corresponding member variable but not a single character for the `Q_PROPERTY` line.

Update: It seems to work with Qt5.1 which expands the user macros properly. Qt4.8 does not work, Qt5.0 has not been tested. See [#QTBUG-35](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35?attachmentOrder=desc) (thanks to ??).

Comment: Note that `Q_PROPERTY()` should expand to nothing by the preprocessor unless `Q_MOC_RUN` is defined. `Q_PROPERTY()` is not intended to be seen by the compiler, only by `moc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

moc in Qt4.x does not recognize Q_ macros within preprocessor macros.

moc in Qt5.x expands the preprocessor macros before parsing the Q_ macros.

Answer (score 0):

You have  a bug too in the lines

```
Set##member##(_type _arg_##member) \
_type Get##member##() const\
```

because of ##() which is evaluated to

```
SetArg(
_type GetArg(
```

by gcc and rejected (MSVC ignores it).

Try the following corrected version and it should work:

```
#define MachAlles(member, _type) \
  public: \
  /**
   * Set member of type _type.
   * @see m_##member for a more detailed description
   */ \
  void Set##member(_type _arg_##member) \
  { \
    m_##member = _arg_##member;\
  } \
  /**
   * Get member of type _type.
   * @see m_##member for a more detailed description
   */ \
  _type Get##member() const\
  { \
    return m_##member;\
  } \
  private: \
    _type m_##member; \
  Q_PROPERTY(_type member READ Get##member WRITE Set##member)
```

Comment: You are right, thanks for the clarification. However, this does not directly affect the Q_PROPERTY issue with Qt's meta object compiler.