# Forwarding Q_PROPERTY from one class to another

Tags: c++, macros, qml, qtquick2

I have a GUI component written using QtWidgets and I have created a QtQuick wrapper for the component by inheriting `QQuickItem`. The original component expose a number of properties that can be exposed directly, while some properties require introducing new classes derived from `QQuickItem`. Is there a more elegant way to do this.

```
class MyQuickItem : public QQuickItem {
  Q_OBJECT
 public:
  ...
  Q_PROPERTY(int someProperty READ getSomeProperty WRITE setSomeProperty);
  int getSomeProperty() const {
    return m_myQtWidget->getSomeProperty();
    // return m_myQtWidget->property("someProperty").toInt();
  }
  void setSomeProperty(int val) {
    m_myQtWidget->setSomeProperty(val);
  }
 private:
  MyQtWidget* m_myQtWidget;
};

class MyQtWidget : public QWidget {
 Q_OBJECT
 ...
};
```

Is there a way to get around this stupid boiler plate coding. I am thinking is it possible to create a replacement macro for `Q_PROPERTY` which accepts expressions to be evaluated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that we cannot inherit from both `QtWidget` AND `QtQuickItem` because both are subclass of `QObject` and Qt MOC simply does not support this. It also does not support templates of QObject-based classes.

So unfortunately we have to write additional code to pass properties through one way or another.

#### With inheritance

First of all I'd like to note that there is no reason to embed pointless `QtWidget`s into `QQuickItem`s. So I suggest separating common logic into a base class like this:

```
class MyBaseItem {...};
//Please note that QObject-based class MUST always be first in inheritance list!
class MyQuickItem : public QQuickItem, public MyBaseItem {...};
class MyQtWidget : public QWidget, public MyBaseItem {...};
```

To lessen the amount of passthrough code we will need to define macros like these:

```
#define PASSTHROUGH_Q_PROPERTY_GETSET(VALTYPE,PROPNAME) \
  Q_PROPERTY( VALTYPE PROPNAME READ get_ ## PROPNAME WRITE set_ ## PROPNAME )

#define PASSTHROUGH_Q_PROPERTY_VALUE(VALTYPE,PROPNAME) \
  PASSTHROUGH_Q_PROPERTY_GETSET(VALTYPE, PROPNAME) \
  VALTYPE get ## PROPNAME () const { return m_ ## PROPNAME (); } \
  void set ## PROPNAME (VALTYPE val) { m_ ## PROPNAME = val; }
```

Explanation:

> Although moc parses the header instead of compiling it, starting with Qt5 [we can apparently use Q_macros in another macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618893/q-property-macro-within-another-macro)

> This code makes use of [token-pasting preprocessor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/token-pasting-operator-hash-hash?view=msvc-160) `##` which glues two parts of identifier together, this includes macro parameters. So `#define F(A) my ## A` will result in `int F(thing);` being equivalent to `int mything;`

You will need to create base properties this way:

```
class MyBaseItem 
{
public:
  int get_someProperty() { return 42; } // obtain value
  void set_someProperty(int val) {} // set data to val

protected:
  float m_myValueProperty; //a second property, this is a simple number
};
```

Then in both heir classes you can add them as `Q_PROPERTY`s this way:

```
class MyQuickItem : public QQuickItem, public MyBaseItem 
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  PASSTHROUGH_Q_PROPERTY_GETSET(int, someProperty)
  PASSTHROUGH_Q_PROPERTY_VALUE(float, myValueProperty)
};
```

This code has to be duplicated into each of two heir classes because moc does not support templates. I don't think it supports mid-class `#include` either but I haven't tested that.

It should be easily evident how to add support for signals, and read-only properties, and such.

Unfortunately, C/C++ preprocessor does not allow to alter identifier case so you will end up with ugly `set_myProperty` instead of proper camelCase `setMyProperty`. If you want latter badly enough you will need do have an additional macro parameter `UPCASE_PROPNAME` set to capitalized `MyProperty` - in addition to `myProperty` which is still needed. See example of this approach in next section.

#### No inheritance

In case creating a base class is not viable for some reason here is the code that you originally requested but beware of problems that may result from embedding stale QWidgets

```
#define PASSTHROUGH_Q_PROPERTY(VALTYPE,PROPNAME,UNAME) \
  Q_PROPERTY(VALTYPE PROPNAME READ get ## UNAME WRITE set ## UNAME ); \
  VALTYPE get ## UNAME () const { return m_myQtWidget->get ## UNAME (); } \
  void set ## UNAME (VALTYPE val) { m_myQtWidget->set ## UNAME (val); }
```

usage:

```
PASSTHROUGH_Q_PROPERTY(int, someProperty, SomeProperty)
```

Comment: Inheritance with a common base class is not possible in my case. The class inheriting from  `QWidget` is 3rd party and rather large (30k LOC and a big hierarcy) and I would like to leave it as is. I will try your suggestion of defining the properties using a macro. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps I will need a few macros supporting `NOTIFY`, 'CONSTANT' and 'READ/WRITE' and inherit from the 3rd party code, so I can emit the relevant signals. At least it is more elegant than my current boiler plate code

Comment: That may be quite an perilous task then. I believe it would be best if you adapt the solution to your exact circumstances then. Do you understand how the macros work and how to modify them to fit your needs?

Comment: I understand the macros, no problem at all. Thought that there maybe was some  Qt-clever way of doing it, hence my question. It is the www.qcustomplot.com that I am wrapping.

Comment: Unfortunately, not that I know of. C++ code itself could probably get around this hurdle in a number of ways but MOC is very limited.

Comment: You could also create a QML wrapper and use `property alias` for every property that needs to be forwarded.